# Multiple sql statements in spring batch writer

Tags: sql, spring, db2, spring-batch

I want to know if it is possible to execute two statements in a spring batch writer? I DO NOT want to use multiple writers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can...

```
public class CustomItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T> {

    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
       //Execute as many statements as you want 
    }

}
```

Comment: What if we have multiple entities (multiple tables) to be passed from ItemProcessor to ItemWriter. Since ItemWriter can hold only one Class, Do we have any option to send multiple entities and perform RepositoryClass.saveall() method of CRUDRepository class?